# What should I have done instead in these reviews?

Tags: discussion, support, review-suspension

I got suspended from reviewing with the following message:

> You’ve been suspended from reviewing. You will be able to review again in 2 days.
>
> The following tasks were handled incorrectly:
>
> - [/review/first-answers/34037885](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/34037885)
> - [/review/first-answers/34101560](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/34101560)
>
> We suspect that you are not actually reviewing the tasks.
>
> Poor reviews negatively affect the community. Please give each task
> adequate attention in the future.
>
> In the meantime, you can refer to the help center for more information
> and revisit your recent reviews.

For both the audits I got the "STOP! Look and listen" message but there was no explanation on why my action was wrong.

I didn't understand why "Looks OK" was the wrong action in [the first failed audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/34037885) (The answer provides an explanation on why this happens- Should it contain more details/an example like the other answers or it is something else?)

I didn't know much about the topic of the second question and [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/34101560), I figured that the answer should provide some more explanation and so chose "Share Feedback". I think I should have chose "Skip" instead since I didn't knew much about the topic and so wouldn't be the right person to review this.

I don't oppose my suspension but I would like to know why I was wrong in both the cases and what I should have done instead.

Comment: In the case of the first audit, the same answer (albeit with much more detail) was given more than 10 years ago. There are already 9 answers to the question. It is unnecessary to add another answer that merely repeats the existing ones.

Comment: “  didn't know much about the topic of the second question and its answer, I figured that the answer should provide some more explanation and so chose "Share Feedback". ” - There was absolutely nothing wrong with the second answer, anything other than “no action required”, would be an improper action. The first answer was deleted, since it was a comment, submitted as an answer

Comment: The first one (about 'Color=ChuckNorris') is about a "famous" Fact/Thread, that Answer looks pretty Low Quality to me (without checking the whole Thread and studying all existing Answers) , probably a poor Copy of other/previous Answers, even possibly ChatGPT-generated... // The 2nd one (the vague "On my side, it seems to" with 33+ Upvotes) is just a Low Quality Answer, I would also never have qualified it "Looks OK", which is obviously what the System expected because of the "+33"..., so it just looks like an obvious Audit I would think... :Tja:

Comment: For [34037885](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/34037885), it looks like ChatGPT has been employed to do some of the work (or good old plagiarism). Look at the completely different writing styles for, say, the last 10 answers.

Comment: "didn't know much about the topic of the second question and its answer" -> skip. If you don't know, skip. 100% safe choice.

Comment: Regardless if the second answer is a LQA or an acceptable answer, is besides the point.  Had the author perform an in-depth analysis of both answers they would have passed both audits.  With that said, the second answer, has 33 upvotes.  Until the other day, after I downvoted it, actually has 0 downvotes.  **So there is no wonder a contribution with 33 upvotes and 0 downvotes became an audit.** I see a lot of users acknowledging it perhaps is actually a LQA, but without downvotes, it will remain as an audit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first audit you cite, you would have seen the "Other answers" tab and that there were ***45 other answers***.<sup>1</sup> That's a lot.

One of the tasks for reviewing First (and Late) Answers is to check that the answer offers something *new* and which has not already been explained in any of the earlier (in this case, *much earlier*) answers. Had you done that, you would have seen that, in this case, the answer really offers nothing new. You may then have added a comment or downvoted – and either of those actions would have passed the audit. (It is also important to check that the new answer doesn't directly copy an existing one; if it does, then it should be flagged as  plagiarism.)

In the second case, you have already said what you *should* have done: "Skip!" If you don't know much about the topic, then how accurate/valuable would any of your feedback be?

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that I may have been a bit harsh, here. Of those 45 other answers, many have also been deleted and, for reviewers with < 10k rep., that tab may have only counted the non-deleted answers – of which there are 9. But the point I made still holds.

Answer (score 7):

> I didn't understand why "Looks OK" was the wrong action in the first failed audit (The answer provides an explanation on why this happens- Should it contain more details/an example like the other answers or it is something else?)

You indicated an answer that had been deleted was content that didn’t need improvement. The answer, of course, appears to have been deleted since it was primarily a comment. I can only assume it was deleted by the author and/or by the community. **Had you downvoted the low-quality contribution, you would have been told it was an audit and passed.**

> I didn't know much about the topic of the second question and its answer. I figured that the answer should provide some more explanation and so I chose "Share Feedback". I think I should have chosen "Skip" instead since I didn't know much about the topic and so wouldn't be the right person to review this.

“Share Feedback” is meant to indicate there is a problem with a contribution. That most certainly wasn’t the case. Yes; If you are unable to determine the difference between a contribution that doesn’t need to be improved then you should skip the review.

Opening reviews in another tab in the future will help you identify if there is a problem with a contribution or if you’re dealing with a helpful high quality contribution.

Comment: "*I can only assume it was deleted by the author and/or by the community.*" To clarify: it was deleted via a Low quality answers review where 4 out of 5 users voted to delete it.

Comment: @VLAZ - I kind of figured it was deleted by the community (through review or by vote) or  by the author due to the amount of downvotes it likely recieved

Comment: "Had you upvoted the high quality contribution you would have passed the audit." - **That** is supposed to be a high quality contribution? I have **serious** concerns about [tag:reactjs] [tag:vite], if they're upvoting these "I also encountered the problem and I don't think it's an issue in the code, try fiddling with the environment as that worked for me" answers to +33. **Assuming** that answer is correct, surely the question qualifies as typo/not reproducible?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - I changed my analysis of the second answer, I actually downvoted it, due to your critical analysis of it.  However, it will likely remain a contribution used for audits in future, unless it receives downvotes. If the question was caused by a typo it should be closed, it's age and the fact it has an answer with 33 upvotes, will prevent the removal of the question so there is no risk in knowledge being lost.

Comment: you can't lose that which doesn't exist